# ace editor get position of all the selected text/word

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor

How to get the position of all selected(Highlighted) words in ace editor

I'm using ui-ace(angular module for ace editor), when i try to get the position of all selected texts using getSelection API, it returns only the last selected element position

I was using the below API

```
editor.getSelectionRange()
```

View HTML is

```
      <pre ui-ace="{ useWrapMode : true,
                              showGutter: false,
                              theme: 'textmate',
                              onLoad: aceLoaded,
                              onBlur: aceBlur}" ng-model="configVm.config"

           style="height: 250px" >
```

Is there an API to get all the selected words positions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `editor.selection.getAllRanges()` on ace, (but not sure how to get ace editor instance from angular-ui wrapper

Comment: Perfect it works. I used onLoad handler to get the editor instance